# downloading files using python ftplib showing system can't find the file specified

Tags: python, ftplib

We can use ftplib for full FTP support in Python. I tried to download all files from several root directories by passing the root directory name recursively

```
import sys
import ftplib
import os
from ftplib import FTP

try:
  ftp=FTP("ftpservice.example.com","username","password")
except EOFError as e:
  raise Exception('Disconnection event...!!!')

def downloadFiles(path,destination):

  dest_path = ""
  try:
    ftp.cwd(path)
    os.chdir(destination)
    dest_path = destination[0:len(destination)-1]+path
    os.mkdir(dest_path)
  except OSError:
    print "%s alredy exist"%path
  except ftplib.error_perm:
    raise Exception("error: Invalid entry- could not change to ",path)

  filelist=ftp.nlst()

  for file in filelist:
    try:
        ftp.cwd(path+file+"/")
        downloadFiles(path+file+"/",destination)
    except ftplib.error_perm:
        os.chdir(destination[0:len(destination)-1]+path)
        ftp.retrbinary("RETR "+file, open(os.path.join(dest_path,file),"wb").write)
        print file + " downloaded"
  return

if __name__ == '__main__':

  sources = ["ab","aldf","amrdf","lient","BF"] #root folder of the file tree
  dest="/home/name/ftp_data/"  # place to which the files are download

  for source in sources:
    source = "/%s/"%source
    downloadFiles(source,dest)
  print "\nDownload Completed... !!!"
```

program is executed and downloaded many files, but in between downloading it shows

```
ftplib.error_perm: 550 companymaster.ace: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

why it so?

actually my program lists all items under a directory then download each item if the item is not a directory.

yet I am getting "The system cannot find the file specified".
I am really confused.

any help?